# How to let Visual Studio 2017 prefer TFS over GIT when opening a solution?

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

In our team we are working with TFS in all our projects, but I have the need now to publish one of our project also on a Git repo.

I initialized a Git repository in the same folder but now when I load the solution Visual Studio always prefer Git over TFS as version control system.

Is there a possibility to let Visual Studio ignore .git folder or prefer TFS over Git?

Comment: No, once it find a '.git' folder, VS assume you are using git. So you can't use both at the same time.

Comment: The only way I have found so far is: rename the `.git` folder, start VS, connect to TFS, restore `.git` folder name.